# cursor sometimes changes from a vertical line to an underscore in Rstudio

Tags: windows-10, rstudio

I am using R-studio 3.3.3 on a 64 bit windows 10 Acer laptop. I am new to programming in R and I just discovered that my cursor sometimes changes from a vertical line to an underscore in R-studio. Could someone help tell me why?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Press  the <kbd>Insert</kbd> button on your keyboard.

Comment: Some keyboards don't have the Insert button, so for me for example, I needed to press fn+E

Answer (score 33):

This is a very common operation in different software and platforms. The underscore means that you are in **Overwrite** mode, meaning that anything you type *will overwrite the text at the cursor position*.

The "normal" cursor indicates that you are in *insert* mode and all text you type *will force the rest of the line to move further*.

Switching between these modes happens by pressing the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key on your keyboard (usually there are two of them, one somewhere above of the arrow keys and another on the Num Pad).

Answer (score 6):

Right click and select Reload.

Comment: This is useful if you work on a remote computer, especially while working between different platforms (like mac and windows, like in my case) and the shortcuts don't work.

Answer (score 4):

press ins button or fn+ins to solve this problem underscore cursor means you are on overwrite mode

Answer (score 2):

This can happen when trying to press the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key - the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key is to left side of <kbd>Delete.</kbd>

Press Insert again to correct this.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue by simply clicking 'insert' keyboard key. The cursor in RStudio changed from underscore to vertical.

Answer (score 0):

shift + insert at a same time from keyboard

Answer (score 0):

For those using HP laptops: the only solution will be to turn on your numeric key `num` which is below the `home` key at the top right corner of your keypad/keyboard; on the same key, you'll see the inscription "lock". Then hit `alt` key on the left of the long `spacebar` on your keypad/keyboard. Then hold it together with the `0` key on the bottom right side of the keypad/keyboard with the inscription `ins` which is the same as the `insert` key. You should be able to get back the vertical cursor line. Hope this works for someone.

Answer (score 0):

with hp laptops: First, turn OFF lum-lock feature by hitting the num-lock button. Then, hit the 0-ins key, which is located in the number keypad area.

Answer (score 0):

Click on Numlocck and hit 0. This will act as insert if you don't have a direct insert button.